# How to find substring of href with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following output.

```
<tr id='row_27' valign='top'>
...
...

<td width="5%"><a href="http://localhost/daikon2/index.php/projects/admin/delete_log/6/6/27" class="deleteme"><img src="http://localhost/daikon2/assets/icons/delete.png"  alt="delete"  title="Delete Log" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the last segments 27 in the href with JavaScript.

I tried the following but nothing happened.

```
var id =href.substring(href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                        alert (id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, how are you getting the `href` variable? Here's one way:

```
var href = document.getElementById("row_27").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
```

I would suggest using the `slice` method of the string, which takes a substring from the index to the end of the string if you specify only one parameter:

```
var id = href.slice(href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
alert(id);
```